# Mongolab instance in which availability zone?

Tags: amazon-ec2, mlab

From their UI, I can only see it is in AWS us-east-1, anywhere I can find out is it in us-east-1b/1c/1d ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in [this blog](http://harish11g.blogspot.com/2012/07/amazon-availability-zones-aws-az.html), availability zones are logical, not physical. So even if we did show which of our account's logical AZs your server was in (we put each server in a cluster in a different AZ), it wouldn't be meaningful to you. Rather than confuse, we leave the information out.

> Availability Zones are not the same across AWS accounts. There is a common misconception that an AZ name like "US-east-1a" identifies a specific physical availability zone for everyone.  The fact is that AWS can map/remap the same AZ name to different physical availability zones across multiple accounts. The Availability Zone us-east-1a for account A is not necessarily the same as us-east-1a for account B. Zone assignments are mapped independently for each account. This is important when our infrastructure or use cases spans across multiple accounts. Example: Infrastructure provisioned through Account-A and Load Testing Agents are launched through Account-B, and both pointing to "US-east-1a" may not map to same AZ.